# Why is my if-condition inside a for-loop not true?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

I started learning C++ and after learning some basics, I wanted to expand my knowledge with smaller projects. I started with a simple calculator that can process two numbers. Then I wanted to program a calculator that asks the user for the amount of numbers to be processed and then processes them with different operations from left to right.

To do this, I created a vector and a for loop which iterates over the index of the vector up to the amount of numbers entered. So that my loop counter does not become larger than my last vector index, I have added an If statement, which changes the calculation and then ends the loop to print the result. The problem is, that my if condition is not seen as true even though I think it should be true. Can someone point out, why this is and give me a hint or solution on how to fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    //Declare variables
    int qty_numbers = 0;
    int case_operation;
    double result = 0;
    double input_numbers;

    std::cout << "Please enter the amount of numbers:\n";
    std::cin >> qty_numbers;

    //Initialize a vector named numbers
    std::vector<double> numbers;
    
    std::cout << "Please enter the numbers:\n";

    //Let the user enter the numbers which get stored into the vector numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < qty_numbers; i++) {
        std::cin >> input_numbers;
        numbers.push_back(input_numbers);
    }

    //Process the first two numbers entered
    if (result == 0) {
        std::cout << "Please select the arithmetic operation:\n";
        std::cout << "1: Addition\n";
        std::cout << "2: Subtraction\n";
        std::cout << "3: Multiplication\n";
        std::cout << "4: Division\n";
        std::cout << "5: Exit program\n";
        std::cin >> case_operation;
        switch (case_operation) {
        case 1: //Addition
            result = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
            break;
        case 2: //Subtraction
            result = numbers[0] - numbers[1];
            break;
        case 3: //Multiplication
            result = numbers[0] * numbers[1];
            break;
        case 4: //Division
            result = numbers[0] / numbers[1];
            break;
        case 5: //Exit program
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Error!\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    //Loop to calculate the 3rd, 4th ... number with the result of the previous calculation (just left to right)
    for (int i = 1; i < qty_numbers; i++) {
        std::cout << i;
        std::cout << qty_numbers - 1;

        //If the index would go out of bounds calculate with the last index of the vector and end the loop
        if (i == qty_numbers - 1) { //Problem: The if condition is not correct and therefore this block is skipped.
            std::cout << "Please select the arithmetic ########## operation:\n";
            std::cout << "1: Addition\n";
            std::cout << "2: Subtraction\n";
            std::cout << "3: Multiplication\n";
            std::cout << "4: Division\n";
            std::cout << "5: Exit program\n";
            std::cin >> case_operation;
            switch (case_operation) {
                case 1: //Addition
                    result = result + numbers[i + 1];
                    break;
                case 2: //Subtraction
                    result = result - numbers[i + 1];
                    break;
                case 3: //Multiplication
                    result = result * numbers[i + 1];
                    break;
                case 4: //Division
                    result = result / numbers[i + 1];
                    break;
                case 5: //Exit program
                    return 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cout << "Error!\n";
                    break;
            };
            break;
        }
        
        //Calculate with the next number except the last (last would be if-statement before)                
        std::cout << "Please select the arithmetic operation:\n";
        std::cout << "1: Addition\n";
        std::cout << "2: Subtraction\n";
        std::cout << "3: Multiplication\n";
        std::cout << "4: Division\n";
        std::cout << "5: Exit program\n";
        std::cin >> case_operation;
        switch (case_operation) {
            case 1: //Addition
                result = result + numbers[i + 2];
                break;
            case 2: //Subtraction
                result = result - numbers[i + 2];
                break;
            case 3: //Multiplication
                result = result * numbers[i + 2];
                break;
            case 4: //Division
                result = result / numbers[i + 2];
                break;
            case 5: //Exit program
                return 0;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout << "Error!\n";
                break;
        }
    
    }

    //Print out the result of the calculation
    std::cout << "Your result is " << result << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I found the problem by changing the printed text (added the ####) to identify if the if-statement is working or not. After running the code the if-statement always gets skipped so my guess is that the condition is false and therefore the if-statement skipped. When changing the condition to e.g. 1 == 1 the if statement is executed and the program ends because of the break at the end of the if statement like intended. Also I tried to test for the scope of my variables and added a cout as the first line of the if-statement to print out the i and qty_numbers variables to see if they are in scope and that worked fine. So my last guess at the moment is the if condition that is not true.

Comment: And did you try printing out the values of `i` and `qty_numbers - 1` on each iteration to see what they look like?

Comment: Yes I did. It started at i = 1 and qty_numbers - 1 = 0, but the if statement still got skipped.

Comment: Well, 1 is not 0, so there is no point in that loop where that condition would become true

Comment: Arrays are indexed from 0 to size-1. Why are you skipping over index 0?

Comment: What values `qty_numbers` takes?

Comment: @UnholySheep That makes sense and I quickly checked if that is the problem. I check again and added the cout. The variables are starting from i = 1 and qty_numbers - 1 = 4 (qty_numbers = 5) so the variables are as intended.

Comment: At this point you will need to post a proper [mre] - this snippet is missing too much context for us to try it out ourselves

Comment: @molbdnilo Before the for-loop I have the calculation for index 0 and 1. The result is then the variable result. I could start with index 0 and change the calculation to e.g. result + numbers[i + 2] if I am correct to skip the first two numbers.

Comment: Since your loop accesses both `numbers[qty_numbers]` and `numbers[qty_numbers+1]`, you should probably think once more about your method.

Comment: I changed the code so the full code is available.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are accessing a vector out of bounds before you get to the if statement that 'doesn't work'.

Suppose `qty_numbers` equals 4. Then in your second loop `for (int i = 1; i < qty_numbers; i++) {` `i` is going to equal 1, then 2. When it equals 2 you evaluate the expression `numbers[i + 2];`. But since `i` equals 2 this is the same as evaluating `numbers[4]` which is an error since the vector has size 4.

Any attempt to access a vector out of bounds gives your program *undefined behaviour* which essentially means you can no longer predict how your program will behave.

I'd like to suggest a fix, but I'm not really sure what the code is supposed to be doing. The loops look confused (and confusing). If you tell me what the code is supposed to do I'll do my best to suggest a fix.

**EDIT**

Just tested your code with my compiler. My compiler causes a crash on `numbers[i + 2]` when `i` equals `qty_numbers - 2` so the problem is as I described above.

Comment: I understand your crash. This is the reason for the if-statement because I ran into the same problem during development. My idea is that the loop is starting with the if-statement to check if this error would occur and then prevent it through adjusting the calculation (numbers[i+1]). Otherwise the loop should continue with the +2 if the index is not out of bounds. I will add some more comments to my code so it hopefully becomes clearer what it is inteded to do.

Comment: @henninfa The if statement does not fix the error, because the error happens **before** the if statement is true. I did run your exact code.

Comment: @henninfa What you should do to get more predictable results is replace `[]` with `at`. So replace `numbers[i]` with `numbers.at(i)`, etc. What this change means is that you will get predictable behaviour on an out of bounds error (specifically you will get an exception thrown).

Comment: I now understand why your answer is different than my thought and is leading to a working result. I got confused with the i = 1 and the index starting at 0. The if-condition has to be: (i == qty_numbers - 2). Thank you for the tip with at as well.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that this if statement `(i == qty_numbers - 1)` will never be correct.

I think you need the code print while program start everytime.

You would useit  without if statement, than the "menu" run after start the progam.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).